# PayPal Payouts (Sandbox) response MALFORMED_REQUEST_ERROR

Tags: firebase, paypal, google-cloud-functions, paypal-sandbox

I'm using PayPal Payouts in my project. I found an issue when creating a Payout. The request is made on Postman (Windows), and Node.js using axios (Firebase Functions).

I received a response `MALFORMED_REQUEST_ERROR` on this request:

```
POST https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payouts

{
  "sender_payout_header": {
    "sender_batch_id": "2018083001",
    "email_subject": "You have a payout!"
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "recipient_type": "EMAIL",
      "amount": {
        "value": "9.87",
        "currency": "USD"
      },
      "note": "Thanks for your patronage!",
      "sender_item_id": "2018083001001",
      "receiver": "receiver@example.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried changing `items[0]/note` to a test value: `POSPYO001`, the API will response `201 Created` as expected.

Why the sandbox is working only on positive/negative test values ? Is this a limitation, or a bug ?

P.S. Sorry for my english.

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Comment: Not yet, I haven't tried this again, and I don't have access to the live mode of PayPal Payouts.